# Strapi v4 plugins.js issue

Tags: strapi

I recently installed strapi v4, and started to install some apps from the marketplace. Some of the apps need updates to a plugin.js file in the config folder.

When I created my app it did not create such a file in the config folder, do I need to create this manually? What am I missing?

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm new to Strapi (and js frameworks generally) and unfortunately the documentation not stating that the file needs to be created has wasted time for me today. Either create the file at project creation or update the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I just needed to create the file and add the plugin :)